# KitKat 4.4.2 error 'unfortunately, the process com.android.systemui has stopped working

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

On Android KitKat 4.4.2 an error comes up 'unfortunately, the process `com.android.systemui` has stopped working.

Now I can't turn it on or off as the error keeps popping up and won't let me do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out that holding the power button down turns it off. Hopefully this will help others.

Comment: Hi @philw I edited both your posts to neaten it up, you can roll them back if you're hot happy with them. No need to apologise for answering a question. I'm not sure why you've been downvoted. It was a legitimate question, and these error messages aren't the easiest at times.